# How to create rules from list of targets in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, templating

My project consists of some configuration files and they are generated from the corresponding templates. e.g. `foo.tmpl` => `foo`. Now I wish to write a Makefile that can generate the corresponding file from the template.

I couldn't have something like this:

```
% : %.tmpl
    generate-from-tmpl $<
```

Since it apply the target to all possible files, however, I only want to restrict its targets to those with a `.tmpl` correspondent. Now I have acquired the list of all templated files:

```
 TEMPLATED_FILES=$(shell find -type f -name "*.tmpl")
 GENERATED_FILES=$(TEMPLATED_FILES:.tmpl=)
```

I wish to have something that looks like:

```
 $(foreach GENERATED_FILES) : $@.tmpl
     generate-from-tmpl $<
```

How can I achieve that? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%: %.tmpl` will attempt to match the target `%`  against any target name but if no matching `%.tmpl` file exists then make will skip that pattern for that target entirely.

I believe that's what you want exactly. Do you have some reason not to think so?

That being said if you want to be more specific what you want is a [Static Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(GENERATED_FILES) : % : %.tmpl
        generate-from-tmpl $<
```

which will only apply to the files in `$(GENERATED_FILES)`.

Also, if your template files are only one directory deep you can use:

```
TEMPLATED_FILES=$(wildcard *.tmpl)
```

instead of the shell and `find` (there are also recursive make wildcard defines available but `find` is reasonable if you need that).

Comment: I misunderstood the implication of `% : %.tmpl`. But thanks to your answer, my confusion is resolved. Thank you!